# Adding secondary X-axis to a Powerbi document connected to SSAS?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Our powerbi document is connected to an SSAS cube (*Connect Live* option).

In our case, we have a Fact table, a DimDate table, and a DimHour table.

I need to show the trend, per day and hour, of all the sales. In my powerbi, I filtered from 5/1-5/5. When I only add `HourKey` to my X-Axis, it shows me the total by hour (no date slicing). It's technically correct because I'm only showing hours, so it's grouping both days by hours:

[image]

When I add `Full Date Alternate Key` so that the X-axis groups by Date and hour, this is what the chart looks like:
[image]

My question: how can I have a secondary X-axis so that I can see the days and the hours?

Answer (score 0):

Under "Data/Drill" menu, click on "Expand next level". In my case, this will show a secondary x-axis of hours:

Goes from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]